# Latex and Overleaf; Two column text, Vertical Blank space and Overfull Text Box

Tags: multiple-columns, vertical-alignment, overleaf

As I can't find an appropriate solution I wanted to look for help here.

In the following picture is an example of my problem (I just changed the text for an sample). Throughout the whole document is a two column layout. In between the text are multiple tables and images that need to fill the whole width of the page (one column). In between the tables should be consecutively two columns instead of one. The main problem are overlapping texts and images and vertical blanc space, which I can not add (\vspace).

Does someone know a solution for the following problems:

- Insert vertical blanc space to adjust the text
- Have two columns between to graphics
- No overfull text box or overlapping texts and images[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE4ne.jpg)

I tried several commands to adjust the vertical blanc space. furthermore I wasnt able to adjust the overlapping text boxes